# Merging Model Objects in Many to Many Relationship

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I am trying to merge together some objects in my Django app. I migrated the data painfully from a Wordpress site.  The site is an archive for incidents against police officers I am using two models (incident, Officers) in a many-to-many relationship with (Details) as an intermediate model.  Here's my models.py:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models

class Officer(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True)
    badge = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.last_name + ', ' + self.first_name

class Incident(models.Model):
    officers2 = models.ManyToManyField(Officer, through='Details')
    case_number = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)

    OFFICE_CHOICES = (
    ('CRA', 'Civilian Review Authority'),
    ('IA', 'Internal Affairs'),
    ('OPCR', 'Office of Police Conduct Review'),
    )
    office = models.CharField(max_length=10,
    choices=OFFICE_CHOICES,
    )

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.case_number

class Details(models.Model):
    officer = models.ForeignKey(Officer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    incident = models.ForeignKey(Incident, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    allegation = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    finding = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    action = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.officer.first_name) + ' '+ unicode(self.officer.last_name)+ ', ' + unicode(self.incident)

    class Meta():
        verbose_name_plural = "details"
```

The problem is that there are currently duplicate incidents with the same case number, relating to different officers.  I am trying to merge those into a single incident while preserving all the information within Details.  Here is the script that I tried, which is not quite working.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from police_archive.models import Incident, Details, Officer
from django.db.models import Count



def run() :

    #get list of duplicates
    list=Incident.objects.values('case_number').annotate(case_number_count=Count('case_number')).exclude(case_number_count=1)
    g= []

    #make list of case numbers
    for item in list:
        g.append(item['case_number'])



    #first entry was empty, remove first entry
    for number in g[1:] :

        #get list of incident objets
        old_incidents=Incident.objects.filter(case_number=number);

        #make new object to replace old ones
        new_incident = Incident(case_number=number)
        new_incident.office=old_incidents[0].office

        #filter out all details which match one of the incidents
        details_list=Details.objects.none()
        for incident in old_incidents:
            print incident.officer2
            results=Details.objects.filter(incident=incident)
            details_list = details_list | results

        #delete old_incidents so that details can be modified
        old_incidents.delete()

        #create new details objects pointing to new incident object, delete old details object
        for details in details_list:
            new_details = Details(incident=new_incident,officer=details.officer, allegation=details.allegation, finding=details.finding, action=details.action)
            new_details.save()
            details.delete()
            #details.save()
        new_incident.save()
```

The results of this script are to create the incident objects properly, but the details objects do not get created. I've tried micro versions of the script in the shell and had good results.  I'm currently out of ideas; let me know if you have any.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to save `new_incident` before you save the details. You are saving the new details before the new incident is in the database.

Comment: I have actually tried it this way as well, and I still get the same result.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding your code, it always deletes the original details from the database. If you need to make any changes to the code, you'd have to restore the db from a backup in order to try again. Is that what you're doing, or am I missing something?

Comment: No that's the intention. Delete the old, save the new. Originally I tried just modifying the old, but that wasn't working so I tried help.  I have been restoring that data from a backup.  Thanks for looking at this with me!

Comment: In the code as written in your question, before you save `new_incident`, `new_incident.id` should be `None`. And if you save `new_details` without a foreign key for `incident` it should give you an error message. If you didn't get an error, that makes me think `details_list` must be empty.